# Ruby on Rails: What is the best way to get all the unique values of a column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

What I want to do is get all the unique values already assigned to a particular model's attribute. Is there a canonical method, or a best way to do this? Also, It would be helpful if the technique was not database specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Vendor.select(:event_id).uniq
```

Return

```
 #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Vendor id: nil, event_id: 6>, #<Vendor id: nil, event_id: 2>, #<Vendor id: nil, event_id: 1>, #<Vendor id: nil, event_id: 3>, #<Vendor id: nil, event_id: 10>, #<Vendor id: nil, event_id: 5>, #<Vendor id: nil, event_id: 7>]>
```

Or

```
Vendor.select(:event_id).map(&:event_id).uniq
```

Return

```
=> [2, 3, 1, 5, 10, 7, 6]
```

Or

```
Vendor.select(:event_id).uniq.pluck(:event_id)
```

Return

```
=> [6, 2, 1, 3, 10, 5, 7]
```

Comment: Vendor.select(:event_id).uniq.pluck(:event_id) is exactly what I was looking for. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
ModelName.distinct.pluck(:attribute)
```

where

Replace `ModelName` with your model name

and `attribute` with the column name

For eg:
In a `Post` model, if you want to list all the unique titles

```
Post.distinct.pluck(:title)
```

distinct was added in `Rails4`, for `Rails3` use below:

```
Post.uniq.pluck(:title)
```

Comment: I get undefined method 'distinct' for #<Class:0xXXXXXX>

Answer (score 0):

Using ActiveRecord (fine)

```
Model.select(:field).uniq
```

Using ActiveRecord (faster)

```
Model.uniq.pluck(:field)
```

Using [`Array#uniq`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-uniq) (not recommendable for large collections)

```
Model.all.uniq(&:field)
```